# replace space in a string at random position in vb.net

Tags: regex, vb.net, string, richtextbox

I want to select a random space in a string and replace it with a word (%word%) but there is a problem. The position cannot be fixed as i want it to be inserted at a random break. Few things which iam considering :

1)break the string at a space and merge it with the word
2) find a random space and replace it with the word. I like this point and so far all i have is break the selectedtext into string array and then iterate over each line. But i don't know how to find a random string position? Any short and sweet code please?

```
  If (rtfArticle.SelectedText.Length > 0) Then
        Dim strArray As String() = rtfArticle.SelectedText.Split(New Char() {ChrW(10)})
        For Each str3 As String In strArray
            If (str3.Contains(" ") = True) Then

            End If
        Next
    End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could locate the spaces in the string, pick one by random, and replace it. Something like:

```
' Get string
Dim data As String = rtfArticle.SelectedText
' Get space positions
Dim spaces As New List(Of Integer)
For i As Integer = 0 to data.Length - 1
  If data(i) = " "C Then spaces.Add(i)
Next
' Get a random space
Dim rnd As New Random()
Dim pos As Integer = spaces(rnd.Next(spaces.Length))
' Remove the space
data = data.Remove(pos, 1)
' Insert the replacement
data = data.Insert(pos, "%word%")
' Put the string back
rtfArticle.SelectedText = data
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `Random` class to generate a random position index.

```
  Dim testString = "This is just a test for random position"
  Dim random = New Random()
  Dim randomPos = random.Next(0, testString.Length - 1)
  Debug.Print(String.Format("Char at Pos {0} = {1}", randomPos, testString.ElementAt(randomPos)))
```